# Is there a Json2Csharp.com for Xml?

Tags: c#, xml

I use Json2Csharp.com all the time. Saves me so much work.
Is there a similar tool for XML? (like Xml2Csharp.com)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for such purposes. It is not a website, but could help you to solve your problem.

Comment: That tool creates the ugliest classes.

Comment: @JerryNixon right, but sorry man, that is all what I have to suggest :(

Answer (score 2):

The same site now supports xml conversion, hope that helps
 https://json2csharp.com/xml-to-csharp

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's there http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/
and it is more itteligent converter than xsd.exe or Visual Studio "Special Paste" (for xml with many fields it creates pure class with strong typed fields instead class with array of System.Object and Enum for identification fields like VS or xsd.exe do)